# Two separate captioned figures on the same line

Tags: graphics, subcaption

I am working in a 2 column environment (IEEE trans format), and need to show three groups of figures, first group has 3 images so they all fall in the first line, no issue. Second and third groups have 2 and 1 images each. So when I write `\caption`, the third group goes to the next line. How can I have both the figures on the same line by modifying the code below?

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure*}[htb]
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}}%
\caption{One group}
\label{one}
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}}
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}}
\caption{Another group}
\label{two}
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}}%
\caption{A third group}
\label{three}
\end{figure*}
```

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood you, you like to have two rows of images with three captions:

[image]

With use of `minipage`s you can group images in the second row:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, below skip=2ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}\hfil
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{demoing}%
\caption{One group}
\label{one}

\begin{minipage}[t] {0.65\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{demoing}\ 
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{demoing}
\caption{Another group}
\label{two}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t] {0.35\linewidth}%
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{demoing}%
\caption{A third group}
\label{three}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```